# Displaying labels created using LabelLayer only at certain scales in ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using ESRI Javascript 3.7 framework to develop a map application, in it I am trying to display labels created using LabelLayer at certain scales only, say from 1:1 to 1:500 scale only.

How can I achieve this?

I played a little with ScaleDependentRenderer but it results in 2 firebug exceptions. Not sure if the ScaleDependentRenderer is the right answer or not.

```
var occupancyLabelLayer = new esri.layers.LabelLayer({ id: "labels" });
// add the label layer to the map
map.addLayer(occupancyLabelLayer);

var labelField = "FLOOR";
// create a text symbol to define the style of labels

var spaceLabelColor = new dojo.Color("red");
var spaceOccupancyLabel = new esri.symbol.TextSymbol().setColor(spaceLabelColor);
//spaceOccupancyLabel.font.setSize("14pt");
spaceOccupancyLabel.font.setFamily("arial");
var spaceOccupancyLabelRenderer = new esri.renderer.SimpleRenderer(spaceOccupancyLabel);

var spaceLabelScaleDependentRenderer = new ScaleDependentRenderer({
    rendererInfos: [{
        renderer: spaceOccupancyLabelRenderer,
        minScale: 500,
        maxScale: 1
    }]
});

occupancyLabelLayer.addFeatureLayer(featureLayer, spaceLabelScaleDependentRenderer, "${" + labelField + "}");
```

Firebug Exceptions:

```
1)exception in animation handler for: onEnd
http://js.arcgis.com/3.7/ (line 45)
2)TypeError: b is undefined
http://js.arcgis.com/3.7/js/esri/layers/LabelLayer.js    Line 21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All layers in the API support [minScale](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/layer-amd.html#minscale) and [maxScale](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/layer-amd.html#maxscale) (and all tiled layers have minZoom and maxZoom) constructor options. The label layer API ref should document this, I'll make sure we get that updated.

Instead of using a scale dependent renderer, use minScale and maxScale to specify your scales (note that since we're talking scales, max scale is the smaller number as that represents a large scale where more area is visible). Here's an example (zoom in to see labels, if you're on a small screen you might need to zoom in twice):  http://jsbin.com/aCicEhe

Relevant code:

```
var labels = new LabelLayer({ 
  id: "labels",
  minScale: 10000000,
  maxScale: 0
});
```