# How to get/set label scale ranges (e.g. minScale) in ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy

For a layer object `lyr`, one can programmatically set the minScale in arcpy as such:

```
lyr.minScale = 150000
```

For a *label*, one can manually set the scale range within a dialog in ArcMap. In arcpy, is there a way to programmatically set the minScale for a layer's *label* in much the same way one can for the layer itself?

I see that [it can be done through the JavaScript API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81312/how-to-display-labels-created-using-labellayer-only-at-certain-scales/81431#81431), but I haven't yet found a way via arcpy.  (I have ArcMap 10.1 SP1.)

Comment: Note for future readers: [minScale and maxScale are not present in 10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) and appear to have [shown up in 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the **[LabelClass (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000002t000000)** properties, which is where I believe this would need to be exposed and there is no such property available there either.

Consequently, for this one I suspect your best option will be to submit an **[ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com)**.

There is a generic idea to **[Expose the ArcMap layer properties through ArcPy](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004REY)** which may lead to it being added.

However, I think we will see this functionality sooner if a specific one is submitted.  If you do that post a link to it into your Question so that future visitors can also vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of [using ArcObjects in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/80/753) to get at this information. I leave modifying the values and saving the MXD as an exercise to the reader:

```
import arcpy
from ESRICOMHelpers import *
esriSystem = GetESRIModule("esriSystem")
esriCarto = GetESRIModule("esriCarto")

def enumerate_feature_layers(map):
    uid = NewObj(esriSystem.UID, esriSystem.IUID)
    uid.value = "{E156D7E5-22AF-11D3-9F99-00C04F6BC78E}" # IGeoFeatureLayer
    enumLayer = map.Layers(uid, True)
    enumLayer.Reset()
    layer = enumLayer.Next()
    while layer:
        yield layer
        layer = enumLayer.Next()

def enumerate_label_classes(layer):
    labelClasses = CType(layer, esriCarto.IGeoFeatureLayer).AnnotationProperties
    for i in range(labelClasses.Count):
        labelClass, labelClassId = CType(labelClasses, esriCarto.IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection2).QueryItem(i)
        yield labelClass

def open_map_document(path):
    mxd = NewObj(esriCarto.MapDocument, esriCarto.IMapDocument)
    mxd.Open(path)
    return mxd

def print_label_classes(mxd_path):
    mxd = open_map_document(mxd_path)
    map = mxd.Map[0]
    layers = enumerate_feature_layers(map)
    for layer in layers:
        print layer.Name
        for labelClass in enumerate_label_classes(layer):
            print "\tname: {0}, minScale: {1}, maxScale: {2}".format(labelClass.Class, labelClass.AnnotationMinimumScale, labelClass.AnnotationMaximumScale)
    mxd.Close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mxd_path = r"path\to\map.mxd"
    print_label_classes(mxd_path)
```

Get `comtypes` [here](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/comtypes/).

The `ESRICOMHelpers` module is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5082/753).

Also note that for 10.1 and up you need to [fix `automation.py`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37673/753) in the `comtypes` site package.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid ArcObjects, but if it's not available natively, I guess that's that! I have other tools in this project using it via comtypes, so I won't have too much more work to do. Thanks!